# Transformers Lib - Load Pre-Trained Model Using Docker

Tags: docker, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to load a pre trained model using transformers lib (by hugging-face):

```
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2Model
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2-medium')
```

Using local machine, it starts to download the model.
But with docker I get the following:

```
OSError: Model name 'gpt2-medium' was not found in tokenizers model 
name list (gpt2, gpt2-medium, gpt2-large, gpt2-xl, distilgpt2). We 
assumed 'gpt2-medium' was a path, a model identifier, or url to a 
directory containing vocabulary files named ['vocab.json', 
'merges.txt'] but couldn't find such vocabulary files at this path or url.
```

Any idea why it happens?

Answer (score -1):

It probably means your docker instance doesn't have access to internet